# Can Jinja be used for CSS templating

Tags: css, templates, google-app-engine, jinja2

I just recently started using Jinja2 for HTML templating on Google App Engine and love it.

I heard that the [Django templating engine can be used for other formats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3623070/290340) so why not Jinja2?

Specifically, what I want to do is create stylesheet stubs for specific pages and dynamically combine them server-side.

Does anybody have experience with this?

Comment: As with the question you referenced, this is a better fit for StackOverflow. However, I would give it a try. I can't find any references to people using Jinja for CSS templating, but looking at the syntax, I don't see why it wouldn't be able to. I'd just avoid using user input in your CSS since I wouldn't count on its XSS prevention features to carry over from HTML.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I'll just have to try it. The only downside is, as is the files are currently routed to a static directory. In GAE static directories are locations that are automatically gzipped and cached. By moving them out of the static directory, they'll lose this optimization. I wonder which is faster, fewer file requests, or caching/gzipping?

Comment: Well, they're both faster. Combining CSS is faster on the first request, and caching is faster on the subsequent requests. But you can always do both and copy the Jinja2-generated stylesheet to a static directory each time it's changed.

Comment: Good point. I have no idea how to make it happen but it would definitely be an ideal solution. A post-update hook to compile/minify all the changed files is what's needed. Something like, http://drydrop.binaryage.com/ but without the git/github dependencies.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I could always do a cron job that checks the minor version number daily "os.environ.get('CURRENT_VERSION_ID').rsplit('.', 1);)" and does the compile/minify then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

If you want to have the result you generate cached on the client side and any proxies between you and them (such as Google's) you can set a Cache-Control header in your response such as:

```
self.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=300;'
```

You can probably use zlib to generate a compressed version as well.

If you want to store the generated result so that you don't have to re-generate (on a cache miss) you can store it in memcache (if less than 1MB) and you can store it in the blobstore using the new [files API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) (experimental). You could actually serve it [directly from the blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob) as well using a BlobstoreDownloadHandler.

Comment: Interesting, what about setting the client side cache to its max value and using the query parameter method to force cache updates when the version changes.

Comment: @EvanPlaice That should work. I use that cache busting technique for other resources that are cached for up to a week.